# How do I receive/send information from/to GitHub using android App

Tags: android, eclipse, git, github, github-api

I have a school project where I am supposed to create an Android application that can get notifications from a GitHub project and also be able to send comments to GitHub using the App. I don't really know where to start but I hope there is some API for Git that I can use.

I'm using Eclipse which is kinda new to me and would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 1):

Github has a number of apis that you can use and I'm sure there are many user created ones as well:

[GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/v3/)

I know they recently rolled out
    [Webhooks](http://developer.github.com/webhooks/)

[Some developer guides](http://developer.github.com/guides/)